# Document Library Lookup Column

Tags: list, lookup-column, library, person

I have a sharepoint list of communities.  Each community has an owner (people column).

I have a sharepoint document library and a view that joins the document to a community.

I am not able to show the community owner column on the doc library view... why?
When I select library settings, create column, lookup, Communities of Practice, the list of available columns doesn't show the owner column.

Answer (score 5):

Lookup columns can only be based on 'Single line of text', 'Number' or 'Date and time' columns see [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632#__toc245004237)

So your only option would be to create a 'Single line of text' column and have an event receiver or workflow populate this with the wanted information from the person in the owner field.